# Are state marriage records publicly accessible online?

Tags: united-states, marriage, foia

Are state marriage records publicly accessible online? Is there a database (free or subscription-only) where such information can be found?

Comment: This depends on the state. In Wisconsin, this is a "pay-per-record search" which takes 3-5 days and is run through [Vitalchek](https://www.vitalchek.com/) and runs anywhere from $4 to more than $50 per record search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they're public record throughout the United States, and available online for most of the United States.

I don't know of any single, national repository for marriage records, so I'd recommend Googling around (e.g., "California marriage records" or "San Diego marriage records"). If you're looking for records from a jurisdiction (or time) that are not available online, you could also try using some of the free online genealogy resources, which make those records available. The LDS Church has a particularly powerful service, which, as I recall, will allow you to search for a person and even pull up a scanned copy of licenses that they have available.

Comment: I would generally agree but as to being available online, I strongly suspect that it is a minority of U.S. states. Also, there are no comparable comprehensive databases for divorces.

Comment: Better wording. I meant "a majority of the United States" in the "a majority of the United States disapproves of Donald Trump" sense.